# Inconvenientes al manejar transaccion padre en c# con procedimientos almacenado que manejan transaccion dentro de ellos?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, stored-procedure, automapper, dapper

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente: Estoy utilizando .NET 7 con *dapper*, para la ejecución de procedimientos almacenados. Pasa que hay casos dónde necesito crear una transacción padre, que en caso de que halla algún error con la inserción de varios registros, me deshaga la transacción, es decir, no me haga cambios en la base de datos; cuando lo ejecuto la primera vez, no me lanza inconvenientes, pero cuando lo ejecuto por segunda vez, me indica lo siguiente mensaje,

```
A TransactionScope must be disposed on the same thread that it was created
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En teoria si estoy utilizando transaccion scope y utilizo el método `Complete`, no tengo que hacer un `Dispose`, pero me indica ese mensaje cuando lo ejecuto más de una vez.

Este es mi procedimiento almacenado:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE GenderSave
(
     @GenderId CHAR(1)
    ,@GenderName NVARCHAR(10)
    ,@CreateBy NVARCHAR(60)
    ,@CreationDate DATETIME
    ,@ModifiedBy NVARCHAR(60)
    ,@ModifiedDate DATETIME
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;
    DECLARE @TRANCOUNT INT;
    SET @TRANCOUNT = @@TRANCOUNT;
    BEGIN TRY
        IF @TRANCOUNT = 0
            BEGIN TRANSACTION;
        ELSE
            SAVE TRANSACTION GenderSave;

                IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Genders AS g WHERE g.GenderId = @GenderId)
                    BEGIN
                        RAISERROR('Ya se encuentra un registro en el sistema, con este codigo', 12, 1);
                        RETURN;
                    END

                IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Genders AS g WHERE UPPER(g.GenderName) = UPPER(@GenderName))
                    BEGIN
                        RAISERROR('Ya se encuentra un registro en el sistema, con este genero', 12, 1);
                        RETURN;
                    END
                
                INSERT INTO Genders
                    (
                      GenderId
                     ,GenderName
                     ,CreateBy
                     ,CreationDate
                     ,ModifiedBy
                     ,ModifiedDate
                    )
                OUTPUT inserted.GenderId,
                       inserted.GenderName,
                       inserted.CreateBy,
                       inserted.CreationDate,
                       inserted.ModifiedBy,
                       inserted.ModifiedDate
                VALUES (
                      @GenderId
                     ,@GenderName
                     ,@CreateBy
                     ,@CreationDate
                     ,@ModifiedBy
                     ,@ModifiedDate
                    );

        IF @TRANCOUNT = 0   
            COMMIT;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE @ERRORNUMBER INT, @MESSAGE NVARCHAR(4000), @XACT_STATE INT;
        SELECT @ERRORNUMBER = ERROR_NUMBER(), @MESSAGE = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @XACT_STATE = XACT_STATE();
        IF @XACT_STATE = -1
            ROLLBACK;
        IF @XACT_STATE = 1 AND @TRANCOUNT = 0
            ROLLBACK;
        IF @XACT_STATE = 1 AND @TRANCOUNT > 0
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION GenderSave;

        RAISERROR(@MESSAGE, 16, 1);
    END CATCH
END
GO
```

Y este es el código de la transacción, que estoy utilizando transactionscope para manejar esta parte,

```csharp
public async Task<BaseResponse<GenderResponseDto>> Handle(CreateGenderCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    BaseResponse<GenderResponseDto> response = new BaseResponse<GenderResponseDto>();

    try
    {
        using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions
        {
            IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Serializable
        }))
        {
            Gender gender = await _genderRepository.SaveGender(_mapper.Map<Gender>(request));

            response.IsSuccess = true;
            response.Data = _mapper.Map<GenderResponseDto>(gender);
            response.Message = GlobalMessages.MESSAGE_SAVE;

            scope.Complete();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        response.Message = ex.Message;
    }

    return response;
}
```

Quedo atento a sus comentarios, agradecería su ayuda,

Comment: José, revertí la pregunta a la versión anterior al último cambio. Espero estés de acuerdo en que era lo correcto. Un saludo.

Comment: De acuerdo asi la dejamos para alguien como comentas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema no es que el procedimiento almacenado maneje *otra transacción* dentro de él.

El problema, cómo lo indica el mensaje de error, es que estás iniciando la transacción en un hilo y estás tratando de terminarla en otro. En principio esto no es posible.

Quizás estás cambiando de hilo de manera inadvertida, pero esto lo provoca el uso de métodos asíncronos y el operador `await`.

En .NET 4.5.1 y superiores, tienes la posibilidad de lograr tu cometido activando el `TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption` de la transacción. La idea general sería como esta:

```
using (var transaccion = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
{
   //llamamos un método asíncrono con , lo cual nos promueve a un nuevo hilo de ejecución
   await unMetodoAsincrono();
   //terminamos la transacción dentro de este otro hilo
   transaccion.Complete();
}
```

Si no puedes actualizar a esta versión, tendrás que escribir un método `SaveGender` que sea síncrono para evitar este problema (así lo llamas sin usar el operador `await`).

Comment: hola realiza las modificaciones que me comentas y me lanza otro mensaje de error, edite la pregunta, y te coloque el codigo, que me indica otro mensaje de error, que podria ser

Comment: Nota el metodo saveGender es asincrono si te fijas en el codigo que publique le estoy colocando un await, si no fuera asincrono no tendria que colocarselo, muchas gracias por tu ayuda quedo atento a tus comentarios

Comment: Ese mensaje de ahora es de un problema totalmente nuevo y distinto del anterior. StackOverflow no funciona de esa manera. Si así lo fuera, podrías publicar una pregunta e ir cambiándola cada vez que ocurre un nuevo error hasta terminar el sistema. La idea aquí no es solo brindarte ayuda sino que quede la pregunta y la respuesta para que le pueda servir a alguien con el mismo error en el futuro. En mi opinión, el problema original está resuelto y si con este nuevo error necesitas ayuda, publica una nueva pregunta y revertir los cambios realizados, para que quede la pregunta a la que respondí.

Comment: De acuerdo entiendo gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 1):

No me queda claro el porqué de usar transacciones si al final solamente ejecutas una sentencia de escritura, pero, ya que estás usando transacciones dentro de tu procedimiento almacenado, omite el uso de transacciones en el código.

Comment: Se aplaude tu intención de participar y responder, sin embargo esto no parece ofrecer una respuesta a la pregunta planteada. Podría ser un comentario en la pregunta o, si tu intención es proveer una respuesta completa, quizás te hace falta incluir una mayor explicación de cómo lo que dices resuelve el problema, quizás algo de código. Para más información mira [answer] y para recordar cómo funcionamos aquí puedes volver a hacer el [tour]. Un saludo.

Comment: @Luis lo que pasa es, que dentro de un procedimiento almacenado, utilizo una sentencia de escritura, pero hay veces, que del lado de c# tengo que manejar una transaccion por si insertando un detalle me falla en algun registro, no me guarde los cambios en la base de datos

Comment: @jachguate Hasta hace poco conseguí la puntuación para poder comentar.